# MapView.Markers of a list are not showing on render

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I try using the mapView.markers on a react native app and they worked fine but somehow when I tried to call a list of locations and info from a firebase database they does not show in the map.

I console.log all the data and it shows on terminal but the marks are not rendering
my data is arrange like this:

profiles
.........|_id: 1234
.........|_kind: "kind"
.........|_name: "name"
.........|_location
.................|_0: 38.4015
.................|_1: -122.104641

And my programing

```
<MapView
        onPress={this.props.onPress}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      >
        {this.state.profiles.slice(profileIndex).reverse().map(profile => (
          <MapView.Marker
            key={profile.id}
            coordinate={{ longitude: profile.location[0], latitude: profile.location[1] }}
            Title={profile.name}
            Description={profile.kind}
          >
            <View style={styles.radius2}>
              <Image style={styles.marker} source={require('../images/marcador.png')} />
            </View>
          </MapView.Marker>
        ))}
      </MapView>
```

I expect to see all the markers.

Comment: location is an array or object?

Comment: It is an array i tried as an object too location.a and i had the same result

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you use an array name `profiles` . But in your question, you have mentioned that the array name is `profile`

Comment: the array name is profiles i don't have a problem recognizing al the other data from the array, like kind, id, name, is just that using coordinate={{ longitude: profile.location[0], latitude: profile.location[1]}} does not recognize those values as a numbers